# Efficient IT asset management software

Tags: windows, linux, asset-management

I'm looking for an IT asset management software to store records of (at least) machines and installed applications. It will be used to inventory a large group of Windows workstations and Linux servers.

It should have the following characteristics:

- agentless
- able to create the inventory with minimum hassle via autodiscovery e.g. by logging in with administrative rights on each machine
- preferably Open Source and/or free

Are there other solutions you recommend apart from [GLPI](http://www.glpi-project.org/?lang=en)? Apparently there's [a lot of programs available](http://www.capterra.com/it-asset-management-software/) but I need some advice to separate the wheat from the chaff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend 10-Strike Network Inventory Explorer (you can find it [here](http://www.10-strike.com/networkinventoryexplorer/))
Unfortunately, it's not an open source, but it has an advantage which souits just for you: it allows collecting data via WMI (Windows Management Instrument), without agents' installing. You just need to have administrator rights. 
The program allows generating a lot of reports on installed software and hardware.

Here there is a video which shows how the program works. [Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9dmiiW7HTA)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Lansweeper](http://www.lansweeper.com/) either paid or freeware.

freeware requires a .exe to be run that sends a machines information directly to the server. (logon script)

where as the paid for version allows for automatic scanning of machines within the network (can be windows, most *nix, apple and some vm's) as well as a heap more.

(NOTE: I am not a employee of lansweeper)