# Asset Management System

Tags: data-analysis, reporting, asset-management

I am looking for a system that, preferably, runs "on a cloud instance" such as a paid AWS or other hosted tool that is responsible for asset management. Presently we're running an internally developed system that 1 person has designed, and they unfortunately do not have the time or resources to invest in expanding this.

The current system does:

1. Imports a spreadsheet from our supplier with Serial Number, an
   "asset number", license and keys;
2. Via scripts run from logon GPOs, exports data into a formatted file and places it in an UNC path;
3. Shell script periodically grabs this file, processes it (matches to an item in the database) and updates the tables with relevant data (IP Address, PC Name, User Logged in);

From here, the IT Department are able to manually add fields relevant to this asset (site location, charge method, other associated keys and special notes). This side works fine, but it is lacking a a report capacity aspect we'd like to use.

It does (via Nagios) do SNMP queries and presents itself as a web page, but that's not as reliable as we'd like (and really only pointed at IT Services).

Ideally what we want the system to do is:

1. Run reporting for core system information (IP Address, PC Name, RAM and CPU Usage and Logged On Users);
2. Query event logs for defined events, and make them accessible via the Web (Such as known BSOD codes);
3. Report on system downtime if needed;
4. Allow scripts (via `PSexec` as an example) and applications to be remotely pushed;
5. Have inbuilt MMC and Remote Registry Access

We are happy to use the current system we have purely for location monitoring and whatnot, but if we migrated to an AD-Sync tool I suspect we could use that in it's place - which would be good.

Additionally it would be good if:

1. It worked on multi-platform (Linux, OSX, iOS, Android and Windows);
2. It is agentless for reporting and;
3. It's free!

At the moment the top contender is Lansweeper but we're open to more cheaper options should they arise.

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23342/efficient-it-asset-management-software has been looked into and added to a review.

Comment: https://www.network-inventory-advisor.com/ looks okay, but seemingly only Windows OS

Comment: http://demo.observium.org/device/device=82/ - a good option

Comment: Can you get any help from https://sourceforge.net/directory/os:windows/?q=%22asset+management%22 ? Don't forget to check for Linux too, if applicable

Comment: Do you need the new system to import the "spreadsheet from <y>our supplier"?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul we are happy to use the old system for that metric

Comment: Could you please write a more descriptive title, for instance by also mentioning the most important distinctive feature you want?